# Integrate liquibase extension in liquibase-maven-plugin

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

i would like to integrate one of those [extensions](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/1998865/Available+Extensions)  in liquibase-maven-plugin how can i do please or even how to create my own plugin using liquibase

the plugin in pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find the proper extension coordinates for maven here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase.ext

Which I found via the documentation for Liqiubase / Maven integration:
https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/home.html

Ronak